# print bar-code without print dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to create a bar-code using code-128, without displaying it on the form. I want to print it without showing print dialog through bar-code printer on client side.
I am able to create bar-code, I have stored it in hidden div but how to proceed further??
How do I achieve this using JavaScript or C#?

Also, how to set height, width parameter in code??

Comment: Are you talking about a web client or a windows store app or ...?

Comment: Then it's not possible. Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292373/javascript-print-without-print-dialog-box and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252936/print-the-page-without-print-dialog-box

Comment: It is possible in a scene that user would press a print button to tell the browser to print, then your job is just to hide the dialog only. Google for "silent printing", "kiosk printing in chrome". It depends on the browser. If you want to make the printing 100% automatically, good luck! Your only 2 ways are ActiceX and Java Applet, both are really painful,trust me.